# Show button tooltips under buttons while key is pressed

Tags: wpf, button, tooltip

I'd like to know is it possible to:
While f1 key is pressed show tooltips of all buttons in wrappanel.

Code:
myButton.ToolTip = new ToolTip() { Content = "[CTRL + 1]" };

And I think I can handle 'while f1 is pressed', but have no idea how to show tooltip right under button (right now, when f1 is pressed, tooltip appears near cursor position).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom"` on your Button to show tooltip at bottom.

```
ToolTipService.SetPlacement(myButton, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom);

  private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F1)
        {
            ((ToolTip)button1.ToolTip).PlacementTarget = button1;
            ((ToolTip)button1.ToolTip).Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
            ((ToolTip)button1.ToolTip).IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: With code:myButton.ToolTip = new ToolTip() { Content = "CTRL + 1", Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top };  and  ((ToolTip)myButton.ToolTip).StaysOpen = true;
                ((ToolTip)myButton.ToolTip).IsOpen = true; - now opening tooltip in right left corner of window

Comment: Unfortunately still the same. Code should be: http://pastebin.com/brLMrpsT right?